# Which Javascript framework is used in Shopify themes as well as third party themes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, shopify, shopify-template

I am a Shopify store designer. I am learning HTML, CSS, and Javascript to understand Shopify themes code to be able to customize themes for my clients.
But i am confused that which framework of javascript should I learn?
**Do you know which framework of Javascript is used in Shopify themes?**
If yes, then please tell me...
Regards;
Haris

Comment: Why not take a look?

Comment: Sorry, i could not understand what you mean.

Comment: Why not open up dev tools (`F12` or `Cmd + shift + i`) and find out?

Comment: Now i got you. Actually, I have been using dev tools and that helped me sometimes but not always. Using dev tools is not enough to be able to customize the theme code. That's why i learned HTML, CSS and now i am going to learn Javascript, but confused about choosing the framework of javascript.

Comment: Research on https://dev.to instead. StackOverflow is not the right place to ask

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are no fixed criteria here

Many developers of 3rd party theme JS framework and JS processers like `webpack`, `grunt`, and `gulp` now a day to optimize the JS code into theme files.

and some are writing code this `jQuery` as well, but Shopify and major theme developer now adopting the dependency-free approach and now they start shifting the code core JS code and try to reduce the burden from JS libs dependencies while pages are loaded.

So into and I think you need to solid your basic of `Javascript` and it helps you adept any new JS framework or library in future.